# Невозможно найти устанавливаемый ISAM

Tags: visual-basic, ms-access

Нигде не смог найти решение проблемы, включая на этом ресурсе. Как это вообще решается или может есть какая нибудь альтернатива?

```
Module расчёт_зарплаты


Dim DT As New DataTable 'создание объекта таблица данных
Dim DS As New DataSet 'создание объекта набора данных
Sub catch_to_base()
    Dim Connection As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Sorce=MyFermDataBase.accdb")


    Connection.Open()
    Dim fio = frm_admin.fio.Text
    Dim all_day = frm_admin.all_day.Text
    Dim have_day = frm_admin.have_day.Text
    Dim zarplata = ((10000 / all_day) * have_day)
    Dim zapros = "insert into Работник(Фамилия Имя Отчесвто,Рабочех дней в месяц,Фактически отработано дней,Зарплата) values('" & fio & "' , '" & all_day & "','" & have_day & "','" & zarplata & "')"
End Sub
```

End Module

Answer (score 0):

А если "четвёрочку" попробовать? - что скажет?

```
Dim Connection As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source= ...
```